# How to sort a (KEY, VALUE) by VALUE being the value a list of tuples?

Tags: scala

I've encountered a problem that I need to solve.

I have a function that outputs a  KEY  and VALUE like this (where the key is a string character and the value can be a tuple or a list of tuples, depending on the information I am parsing):

```
[String, ( (Int, String), (Int, String), ... , ... )]
```

this could be an example where the output is a KEY String character ("134;4;001;2") and the value is a list of 3 tuples.

```
["134;4;001;2", ( (2, "String 1") ,(4, "String 2"), (16, "String 23") )]
```

What I need to do now is how to sort the value leaving the highest int number in the first position.

Therefore what i would need as the output would be:

```
["134;4;001;2", ( (16, "String 23"), (4, "String 2"), (2, "String 1") )]
```

Comment: You need to modify your question, it's too ambiguous. My suggestion is to add an input sample and the desired output sample.

Comment: I hope its less ambigous now! Thanks!

Comment: "a tuple like this: [String, (...)]" how is this exactly a tuple? You used bracket notation, which makes it a list. Also, you put the second element of that list in round parenthesis to seem like a Tuple2, but then in the example you put three elements instead of two. I'm completely lost, will delete my answer and will post again if the question is properly asked.

Comment: I modified the question! I hope you understand it better now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming:

- Second element in is always a Tuple3 (another tuple of exactly 3 tuples)
- You want the result to be a tuple, with second element being a tuple-of-tuples

Given all that, this would do it:

```
val input = ("134;4;001;2" ,((2, "String 1") ,(4, "String 2"), (16, "String 3")))

type T = (Int, String) // just to make things shorter...

// turn tuple-of-tuples to list, and reverse-sort list by first element
val tupleWithList: (String, List[(Int, String)]) = input match {
  case (header, (t1: T, t2: T, t3: T)) => (header, List(t1, t2, t3).sortBy { case (i, s) => -i })
}

// if you want the result to contain a tuple-of-tuples again (instead of a list):
val result = tupleWithList match {
  case (header: String, List(t1: T, t2: T, t3: T)) => (header, (t1, t2, t3))
}

println(result) 
// prints: (134;4;001;2,((16,String 3),(4,String 2),(2,String 1)))
```